# Push new object into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have this array:

```
var array = [{'ref1': {'Product': 'Car', 'color': 'Red'}}, {'ref2': {'product': 'velo', 'color': 'red'}}]
```

I want to add 'price': '8' to only 'ref1'

How can do this properly?

Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more dynamic code if you do not know for sure whether the object containing the "ref1" property is always at index 0:

```
const insert = (idProp, key, value) => {
  var el = array.find(el => el.hasOwnProperty(idProp));
  if (el) { el[idProp][key] = value }
}
```

then call it via

```
insert('ref1', 'Price', 8)
```

Comment: Thanks B12 it's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it: `array[0]['ref1'].price = 8;`

```js
var array = [
  {'ref1': {'Product': 'Car', 'color': 'Red'}}, {'ref2': {'product': 'velo', 'color': 'red'}}]

array[0]['ref1'].price = 8;

console.log(array)
```

Observation: ref1 has a property `Product` while ref2 has a property `product` in lowercase. This may cause you some problems latter.

Comment: Thanks but :
As price does not exist in the array, I get an error.

Comment: If you get an error you didn't asked the write question

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
var arr = [{'ref1': {'Product': 'Car', 'color': 'Red'}}, {'ref2': {'product': 'velo', 'color': 'red'}}];

console.log(arr);

arr[0]['ref1'].Price = 8;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the ref1 item, then assign the value to the Price parameter.

```
var array = [{'ref1': {'Product': 'Car', 'color': 'Red'}}, {'ref2': {'product': 'velo', 'color': 'red'}}];
var ref1 = array.filter(item => item == {'ref1': {'Product': 'Car', 'color': 'Red'}})[0];
var index = array.indexOf(ref1);
array[index]['Price'] = 8;
```